# Which is better for arabic Babel or Polyglossia

Tags: babel, polyglossia, arabic, chessboard, skak

I need to know for general purpose articles or books.
Which one plays best with figures, diagrams, multicolumns, TOC, enumitem..etc.
and most appreciated if problems with skak, and chessboard are less or totally resolved.

Comment: Please, edit your post to provide a MWE with, at least, `skak` and `chessboard`, and to explain what you mean with ‘problems’.

Comment: that's going to take a long time
but I'll do my best in rewriting this question with more details.

Comment: I would suggest lualatex with babel. If there are problems with chessboard (quite possible as it hasn't been written with RTL in mind) it  will be easier to resolve them with babel.

Comment: I'll try that ASAP.
Thanks

Comment: Try with both and compare the results to see which you prefer. What I might like you might hate, and vice-versa. You are asking about opinions and this site is not really intended for that.